# Having trouble performing a segue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3

Basically I want to perform a segue when the timer reaches a certain value.
However, every time it tries to perform the segue I get this error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   2017-04-26 17:31:56.678558 TypingGame[3675:1262313] fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   (lldb)

This is the snippet of code responsible for the segue:

```
var time2MoveOn = Timer()

//in ViewDidLoad

time2MoveOn = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10.0, target: self, selector: #selector(timeToMoveOn), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)




func timeToMoveOn() {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "endGame", sender: self)
}
```

So theoretically, after 10 seconds have passed it should performSegue but it does not :(.

Comment: Set the exception breakpoint and figure out what is `nil`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked that your segue identifier is spelled correctly?

Comment: have you checked that the error is within the function timeToMoveOn()?

Comment: the error occurs when trying to perform that specific segue with that identifier so I guess it is within that function since it invokes the segue but it doesn't make sense as to why it would create an error.

Comment: Have you tried setting a break point on the "performSegue" command and looking through your variables?

Comment: I had a space in the identifier which hindered it. Renamed the identifier without the space and it worked! Thank you!